# PC folders and files showing in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, installation, python-requests, anaconda, jupyter

Anaconda newbie here. I just downloaded Anaconda on my new PC with Windows 10 however when I open up Jupyter I can see all my personal folders and files from my computer (Desktop, Documents, and Pictures, etc). Can someone tell me if this is normal? I also notice that when I add or create a new folder or document on my computer it shows up in Python and vice versa. I don't remember this happening on my old MacBook so it surprised me now that I have a PC. Does this mean my computer files are being shared online? Is there an easy way to fix this as I wouldn't want any sensitive information like a a W-2 or family photos automatically uploaded to Jupyter. Or should I start from scratch and reinstall Anaconda a certain way? I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: If Jupyter can't see your folder structure how can it navigate anywhere to open up a file?  It's normal

Comment: Just because Jupyter runs in your browser, doesn't mean your files are online.  Jupyter is a local server on your own machine, not open to the internet.  No worries.

Comment: Ok that's reassuring to hear. I guess I am still unclear of why  when I add or create a new folder or document on my computer it shows up in Python and vice versa on my PC but I just checked my Mac Book and this is not the case?

Comment: @Israel Your answer has some formatting problems. To highlight apps' names or interface, use a **bold** (`**` brackets) or *italic* (`*` brackets) font. To start from a new line use *double space* at the end of the line - the question'll be way more clear.

Comment: @Israel Don't use salutations: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: @maciejwww I wasn't aware of this. Understood.

Comment: @Israel Edit it at your leisure.